# How to generate Web Service Client for a WSDL using RAD 8.0.2 and Web Sphere 8.0.2

Tags: jakarta-ee, soap, wsdl, jax-ws, ibm-rad

I am new to IBM RAD 8.0.4 and Web Sphere 8.0.4. I learnt how to create Java Web Service and a WSDL using RAD.  Now I want to write a client for the WSDL I have got. I have target URL available. How do I go about it? Any resources or steps available online? Whenever I search I get RAD 6.0 version tutorials but RAD 8.0.4 is lot different from the tutorial steps. Also, Do I need to install any other suite or framework to make this work like some SOA suite or framework? Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You can right click on the project that your client classes will be created then select "New","Other". You should see wizard now. If you write "Client" on search box you will see "Web Service Client".
After that point you should be fine, enter your url, select implementation and server setting etc.